# This document was generated by a trial version of Telerik Document Processing

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, telerik, richtextbox

I've download the `TelerikEditor` user control that exist on the GitHub repository of Telerik , I've called it on my project and it works fine , but the problem is that I got this warning , I'm searching for a way to remove it , How can I eliminate this warning message?

Note : All Dlls file ( assemblies ) are not trial version , I've checked them using : Property => Details => File Description

https://github.com/telerik/xaml-sdk/tree/master/RichTextBox/TelerikEditor

- This document was generated by a trial version of Telerik Document Processing.

( see the attachment )

[image]

[image]

What should I check from DLLs files to verify what is trial or not ???

Does Telerik update will fix this problem ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my problem by navigating to the GAC and deleting the cached assembly files " Telerik dll files "